# Use of TfidfVectorizer on dataframe

Tags: text-classification, tfidfvectorizer

I have the dataframe which has 3 colums(Positive Reviews,Negative and Score):

```
  negative                                        Positive               Label  
0 [there, were, issues, with, the, wifi, c]     [no, positive]             1  
1 [rooms, could, do, with, a, bit, of, a]   [the, well, meaning, staff]   2.5
```

I want to apply the TfidfVectorizer on the DF.
I have written the following code.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer  
df_x=train_df["Positive"]  
df_y=train_df["Score"]  
cv = TfidfVectorizer()   
df_xcv = cv.fit_transform(df_x)  
a=df_xcv.toarray()  
cv.get_feature_names()
```

which is giving an error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: Please avoid [cross-posting](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/106196/64377) (asking the same question on several sites).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `pd.Series` object to the `cv.fit_transform()` instead of a list/series of strings. So what you could do is to join your lists in each row and then pass them to the Vectorizer method:

```
df['joined_positive'] = df['Positive'].apply(' '.join)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['joined_positive'])
```